# BigQuery Bytes field individual field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with a BYTES field. In every row this field contains 6 bytes. How can I query the table so only rows are returned where the second byte is A, E, 2 or 6?

Thanks in advance,

Evert

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUBSTR` function to extract the byte at that position. Here is an example that you can run:

```
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT b'abcdef' AS s UNION ALL
  SELECT b'ABCDEF' UNION ALL
  SELECT b'123456' UNION ALL
  SELECT b'765432'
)
SELECT s
FROM T
WHERE SUBSTR(s, 2, 1) IN UNNEST(SPLIT(b'AE26', b''));
```

To use your own table, just remove the `WITH T AS (...` part. If you want to match more characters, add them to the list that is passed to `SPLIT`.